# AppCompat 21: name = colorPrimary not working together with name = actionBarStyle

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

When i'm using the item actionBarStyle, colorPrimary doesn't set the color to red.
If i delete the item actionBarStyle, it works. How can i change my code to display the color?

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyStyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyStyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I didn't need to use Widget but just [set the app theme that included colorPrimary in the manifest file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39341616/3681880).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of `Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar` is [`Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml#L24), which doesn't apply a background attribute.

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar" parent="">
    ...
    <item name="background">@null</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@null</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@null</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Instead your parent should be `Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid`, so that you'll inherit the attributes from [`Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml#L58), which applies the background attribute.

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Alternatively, you could just apply the background attribute yourself.

```
<style name="MyStyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Very deep insightful answer. +1